# Firebase Realtime Database Pricing with Query

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about the firebase database pricing. I have about 400,000 rows in the leaderboard of my database, but in my app I just want to load the last 500 rows, so my question will I get charged for the 500 rows loaded when I run the query or will I get charged for all 400,000 rows.

Realtime database charges 5$ per gb stored and 1$ per gb downloaded. I did the calculation with Firestore and found that Realtime Database would be way cheaper if i get charged for the 500 rows and not the 400,000 rows.

I searched all documentation and have not found anything about queries: https://firebase.google.com/pricing
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing

Can someone tell me if I get charged for just the 500 rows in my collection or for all the data in the collection and if there is a way to only get charged for the 500 rows maybe with security rules?

Here is my query code:

```
let queryRef = ref.child("Leaderboard").queryOrdered(byChild: "totalStars").queryLimited(toLast: 500)
```

How the database looks like. (It will have about 500,000 childs same as these and be loaded 200,000 per day, But I just want to be priced on the top 500 that I load and not the whole 500,000 each time a user loads the leaderboard is it possible?)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will only be charged for the number of **Firestore** Documents corresponding to the **result of your query** (not to the number of docs in the collection).

So in your case a maximum of 500 reads, since you would limit the Query to 500 documents.

---

On the other hand, note that the Realtime Database queries are not shallow (while the Firestore ones are) and therefore if you query for a JSON node you'll get **the entire tree under this node**.

Comment: Yes I know this for Firestore but I am asking for the realtime database.

Comment: So if I query for the last 500 or don't I will still get charged for the whole data loaded. What would you recommend in this case since if I use Firestore with 200,000 request per day for 500 rows I will have to pay $60 per day, do you think realtime database is a better option?

Comment: You have to do the math indeed, taking into account the different elements composing the pricing (storage, Network egress, Document reads on one hand and GB stored and
GB downloaded on the other hand).

Comment: @jmapps9 This is a great answer! Let me add one thought; the query in your question is for the RTDB. If that's an option, I would suggest RTDB and denormalizing your data; keep a separate *leaderboard_stars* node that only contains a reference to what's in the leaderboard, or perhaps a very shallow node of reference, name and number of stars and when you need to load the last 500 use that node instead of the Leaderboard node which probably contains a lot more data. Loading 500 very shallow nodes in the RTDB is a tiny amount of data and very low cost.

Comment: @Jay can you please explain to me more, I have a leaderboard where all users will compete and earn starts and I want to filter the leaderboard to the top 500 users based on their total stars. If I create another node other than the leaderboard how will I know if the user got into the top 500. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jay since each time a user gets a new star, the total stars for the user in the leaderboard get's updated.

Comment: @jmapps9 Keep the number of stars earned also in a separate, shallow node. Assuming the users are Firebase users, store the child nodes as a key:value pairs of `uid: number of stars` or perhaps a shallow key: value pair with two child nodes of `uid: player name` and `uid: number of stars` Duplicating data is very common with NoSQL databases - it's part of what makes them so fast and efficient as disk space is cheap. Then you can sort and get the last 500 with only a tiny amount of data.

Comment: Hello @Jay, You may write another answer and the OP may select it as the accepted one.

Comment: @Jay the leaderboard already just includes the total stars, UID, and full name that is everything in it, the table view loads the name and the number of stars next to it, I also need the UID to check if he is in the top 500. My question is is there a way to just have the 500 loaded and priced on the 500.

Comment: @Jay I did the calculations for 500,000 rows in the leaderboard it will cost me 430$ per month when loading all 500,000 rows and filtering the top 500, with Firestore it will cost me $1814. Because the leaderboard will be loaded about 200,000 times per day. So RTDB is still cheaper even when loading the 500,000 rows, but would be way more cheaper if I was priced only on the 500 rows as I only download the 500 rows but I don't know if it is possible maybe with security rules?

Comment: @Jay added the leaderboard image for reference.

Comment: @jmapps9 Look back at this answer because it is correct. You're only charged for what you download, not total nodes in the database. If you've got 5,000,000 nodes, and you query for and download 500, you are only charged for the amount of data contained in those 500 nodes.

Comment: @Jay looking at the answer from Renaud he mentions that I will be charged for the 5,000,000 nodes not the 500 nodes if I am using RTDB. If I am using Firestore I will be charged for the 500 not the 5,000,000.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec can you please confirm your answer as per Jay answer I am only charged for the 500 rows that I download.

Comment: @jmapps9 Jay is right, if you limit your Realtime Database query with one of the `queryLimitedToFirst` and `queryLimitedToLast` methods you actually set a "maximum number of children" to be returned. The potential "problem" is not at this level. The problem may come if some of the children (included in the 500) have themselves some children nodes (or/and grand-children, grand-grand-children, etc): all the date corresponding to those nodes will also be sent to your front end, potentially increasing the cost.

Comment: The problem also comes from the fact that you speak about "rows": while with Firestore this could **more or less** correspond to Documents, with the Realtime Database we cannot use this comparison as the data is store as a JSON tree (with potentially many levels).

Answer (score 2):

Renaud's answer *is the correct one* but let me add some additional information and restate that:

> With the Firebase Real Time Database for downloads you are charged for
>   what is downloaded and not how many nodes you are querying.

So the key is to reduce the amount of data you're downloading. Your nodes are already pretty shallow however, there's a huge savings to be made because in your current structure, the node key (the users uid) is duplicated within the node as a child node, and that's not needed.

You can always get the node key with `snapshot.key` and remove that child node. So it would look like

```
uid
   fullName: "Logan Paul"
   stars: 40
```

Also, I think your calculations are off a bit. It looks like each node would be about 100 bytes of data, and Firebase strings are UTF-8 Encoded so if you download 500 nodes per user per day and you have 200,000 users, that about 38Gb per day (as binary).

Roughly 400 bytes * 500 nodes * 200,000 users * 0.000000000931322574615479 bytes per Gb = 38Gb

so about $38 a day if I did my math correctly.

Comment: I did my calculations per the following:
1. Each document is (146 bytes) for the whole leaderboard if it contains 500,000 document then the total is 0.073 GB
2. If 200,000 users load the 0.073 GB of data each day that is 14,600 GB of data loaded each day so it is around 14,600$ per day. I think there is something wrong 

Comment: Is there a way you can provide me with the cheapest option even if it means using Firestore instead. What would you recommend in my case?

Comment: Because according to Renaud's answer I will get charged for all the nodes in the database and not just the first 500 loaded when using Realtime database.

Comment: @jmapps9 See my comments above.

Comment: @jmapps9 What Renaud said in his answer is you're charged for *number of Firestore Documents corresponding to the result of your query* - note: the results of the query. If you have 1 million documents stored in Firestore, and your query returns 10, you are billed for 10. In the RTDB you're billed for number of bytes returned so you want to focus on returning the least number of bytes. If you return 500 nodes, and each node is 400 bytes, and it's 200,000 per day, its about $38. See the RTDB structure and calculation in my answer.

Comment: @Jay so using the code `let queryRef = ref.child("Leaderboard").queryOrdered(byChild: "totalStars").queryLimited(toLast: 500)` I have 1 million nodes in the Leaderboard and I want to filter all of them by totalStars and return the 500 top ones with the code above, So I will get charged the 500 top ones not all 1 million is that correct?

Comment: So it will be 500 nodes with each node 400 bytes not 1m nodes with each one 400 bytes. That is my questions because I know with Firestore only the result counts so the 500 returned, I want to see if it is the same for RTDB.

Comment: @Jay I think I missed something when using **.queryLimited(toLast: 500)** after **.queryOrdered(byChild: "totalStars")** does it take only 500 nodes and filter them or does it filter all nodes and return the last 500?

Comment: In either RTDB or Firestore, using a limit returns, well, that limit. `.queryLimited(toLast: 500)` will only every return up to 500 and no more. If you only have 10 nodes in total and you limit to 500, it will return however many match your query up to those 10. If you have 1000 nodes and only 300 match the query, only 300 are returned. If you 1,000,000 and 600 match the query, only the last 500 are returned - never any more than that regardless of how many there are total.

Comment: To make it simple, if you have 100 nodes and you query with a limit of 10, you are charged only for 10 nodes data download. "Same as how Firestore works"

Comment: @Ayyappa Just a heads up that [Real Time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) billing not the same as [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing). Billing for the Realm Time Database and Firestore are very different. The RTDB billing is based on qty of data and Firestore is billed by number of reads/writes/deletes.

Comment: Yes, right. I meant in this context about the billing for number of documents/node retrieved. "Same as now Firestore works" refers to the fact that only the retrieved data/documents are charged rather than whole data set.